# Android: Show notification about my pending alarm like it does system alarm app

Tags: android, alarm

I am developing an application, one of the functions of which is the alarm clock. I saw that some applications with such a function can display the time of the next alarm clock, as if it were a system alarm clock. What API can I do this for?

I tried to send the broadcast android.intent.action.ALARM_CHANGED, but this does not work on my device (and somehow it works for other applications).

[image: Imgur]
[image: Imgur]

Comment: do you want just icon notification for your app?

Comment: @AliKhaki I have already added the creation of the usual notification. But I saw that some applications from Google Play (for example, Brain Focus), when they work, affect the system alarm clock icon. I want to do the same.